# Dom not finding dynamically created select box

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery to create two dropdowns dynamically where on change of the first one determines what will be put in the second one as follows:

```
$("#add").click(function () {
var id = Date.now();
var text = " <div class='row' id='" + id + "'><br /> \
<div class='col-md-3'><select class='listOptions' id='myoptions[" + id + "].user'>" + listOptions + "</select></div> \
<div class='col-md-3'><select class='secondOptions' id='myoptions[" + id + "].cars'></select></div></div>";
```

this will create two dropdowns in this format:

```
myoptions[1405087264136].user
myoptions[1405087264136].cars
```

Accessing the first dropdown is easy through

```
$(document).on("change", '.listOptions', function () {...}
```

Now the issue is accessing the second one has baffled me:

I have tried this:

```
currentid = $(this).attr('id').substr(0, 24) + ".cars";
```

But either of these 2 lines return 0

```
alert($("#" + currentid).length);
alert(document.getElementById(currentid).length);
```

**Note:** for some reason, in the console, I am able to access the second option

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `closest` (to get the parent) and `find` to get the related `.secondOptions` element. Try this:

```
$(document).on("change", '.listOptions', function () {
    var currentid = $(this).closest('.row').find('.secondOptions').val();
});
```

Using DOM traversal in this way means you don't need to worry about unique or incremental identifiers.

Comment: What about using `.next()`?

Comment: @MelanciaUK the `select` elements aren't siblings.

Comment: True. I just noticed that.